# Exclude ID from Beautify

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use Atom Beautify and i want to beautify everything in an HTML Page except for a code which is inside a particular ID. I can exclude certain tags like **pre** and **textarea** but not able to exclude by ID. Is there a way to do it?

[image: Here is an Image of Settings]

Comment: I think It accepts only HTML tags.

Comment: Aware of any other beautifer where i can achieve this? @AlokMali

Comment: I know about `Prettier` which comes with `Visual Studio Code` Editor